# .NET to Delphi (string.Substring function)

Tags: .net, delphi

I'm trying port a .NET function to Delphi.

Here is the .NET function:

```
public static string xorEncrypt(string sA, int32 displace)
{
    displace = Math.Abs((((((displace * 82) + (displace / 3)) + (displace % 322)) - (displace % 17)) - ((displace * 7) % 811)));
    string str1 = System.String.Empty;
    string str2 = RWCustom.Custom.EncryptionString;
    int num1 = 0;
    while (num1 < sA.Length) 
    {
        str1 = str1 + (char)((sA.Chars(num1) ^ str2.Chars(((num1 + displace) % str2.Length))));
        num1 = (num1 + 1);
    }
    return str1;
}
```

And here is my function:

```
function xorEncrypt(sA: String; displace: Integer): String;
var
   str1: String;
   str2: String;
   num1: Integer;
begin
   Result := '';
   str1 := '';
   str2 := ''; // ?!?
   num1 := 0;
   displace := Abs((((((displace * 82) + (displace div 3)) + (displace mod 322)) - (displace mod 17)) - ((displace * 7) mod 811)));
   while num1 < sA.Length do
   begin
      str1 := str1 + Char(Ord(sA.Chars[num1]) xor Ord(str2.Chars[((num1 + displace) mod str2.Length)]));
      Inc(num1);
   end;
   Result := str1;
end;
```

So, I already have two problems:

1. string str2 = RWCustom.Custom.EncryptionString;

   ```
   private string EncryptionString
   {
       get
       {
           return this.encrptString.Substring(54, 1447);
       }
   }
   ```

   encrptString is a String, but looking on mscorlib, the Substring function:

   ```
   public string Substring(int32 startIndex, int32 length)
   {
       return this.InternalSubStringWithChecks(startIndex, length, false);
   }
   ```

   And InternalSubStringWithChecks function:

   ```
   internal string InternalSubStringWithChecks(int32 startIndex, int32 length, bool fAlwaysCopy)
   {
       int nt321 = this.Length;
       if (startIndex < 0) 
       {
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndex"));
       }
       if (startIndex > nt321) 
       {
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_StartIndexLargerThanLength"));
       }
       if (length < 0) 
       {
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_NegativeLength"));
       }
       if (startIndex > (nt321 - length)) 
       {
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("length", Environment.GetResourceString("ArgumentOutOfRange_IndexLength"));
       }
       if (length! == 0) 
       {
           return this.Empty;
       }
       return this.InternalSubString(startIndex, length, fAlwaysCopy);
   }
   ```

   I have no idea how should be this in Delphi.
2. (displace / 3) it's a integer division on .NET? Should I change my code to (displace / 3) and set displace to Variant?

Comment: Integer division is div. This function is something of a joke though. It is t real encryption and it doesn't play nice with UTF-16. Where does this function come from and why do you have to use it.

Comment: And as for Substring you can find out what it does from the documentation. I leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: Delphi's equivalent of .NET's `String.Substring()` is [`System.Copy()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Copy) (1-based indexing) and [`TStringHelper.Substring()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TStringHelper.Substring) (0-based indexing). .NET uses 0-based string indexing.

Comment: @Delutto Welcome to Stack Overflow. As others have eluded to, using an `xor`-based algorithm is not encryption at all and is extremely vulnerable to attack. I'm not aware of a Delphi wrapper, but the Windows API has some very capable cryptography functions available, which you should be able to use. Here is the Microsoft docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380252(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @CobusKruger I'm not trying encrypt a text with this function, I'm trying decrypt.
This a encryption for localization files used by a game engine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But I don't understand, that's no value assigned to this variable, what I have to do?

Comment: @Delutto I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @RemyLebeau I asking how should be the code for this str2.
str2.Chars[((num1 + displace) mod str2.Length)]
As you say, it's a Copy function, but there's no value signed, it's empty, this will allways generate a exception, because it's a division by 0, and even ignoring this, there's no sense index a char from a empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having noted my reservations about this kind of "encryption", let me actually answer the question.

You have a few different problems to contend with, the first among which is that your string indexes are mostly going to be off by one. Remember that Delphi strings are one-based, whereas C# uses zero-based strings, so you need to make adjustments for that. I made a few, but just check every string index you see.

The first place that's going to affect you is in your `EncryptionString` function:

```
property EncryptionString: string read GetEncryptionString;
```

and

```
function TMyClassNameHere.GetEncryptionString: string;
begin
  Result := Copy(encrptString, 55, 1447); // Was encrptString.Substring(54, 1447)
end;
```

So while the length remains the same, your string index shifts up by one.

Then, the main function:

```
 class function TMyClassNameHere.xorEncrypt(sA: string; displace: Integer): string;
 var
   str1: string;
   str2: string;
   num1: Integer;
begin
  displace := Abs((((((displace * 82) + (displace / 3)) +
         (displace mod 322)) -
         (displace mod 17)) -
         ((displace * 7) mod 811)));
  str1 := System.String.Empty;
  str2 := RWCustom.Custom.EncryptionString;
  num1 := 1; // Was 0
  while (num1 <= sA.Length)     do
  begin
    str1 := str1 + Char[(sA[num1] xor str2[((num1 + displace) mod str2.Length)])];
    num1 := num1 + 1;
  end;
  Result := str1;
end;
```

I changed to a class function (because the original was static). Also, `num1` is initialised to one instead of zero.

I think the rest of the calculation should be fine, but I obviously can't test because I don't know what the input is or how it is supposed to work. But this is the Delphi translation I came up with within those constraints.

Comment: Thank you. Seeing you set the EncryptionString as property clarified me. I need load the encypted text to a global var "encrptString" before... I missed that at some point on .NET code. And zero-based strings is another thing that I not known too. Getting home I'll try. Thank you again.